# How to find specific file types and tar them?

Tags: linux, terminal, tar

It seems I've got a problem. I've got some different file types in my current directory, and I want to just **tar** the **.png** files. I started with this:

```
 find -name "*.png" | tar -cvf backupp.tar
```

It wouldn't work because I didn't specify which files, so looking on how others did it, I added xargs:

```
find -name "*.png" | xargs tar -cvf backupp.tar
```

It did work this time, and backupp.tar file was created, but here is the problem. I can't seem to extract it. Whenever I type:

```
tar -xvf backupp.tar
```

Nothings happens. I've tried changing chmod and sudo, but nothing gives in.

So, did I type the wrong command completely or is there somethings I just missed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question but a tool question best asked on unix.stackexchange.com. I suggest you delete this one and ask it over there.

Comment: Probably @Rob but I can't post twice in 40 minutes, and I really need help, it's for school and I need the grade to apply for college. Therefore, the more eyes it reaches the better, but I'll take it down as soon as I solve this. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

`tar` expects a list of names as arguments. Your use of `xargs` can be improved by adding the `-print0` option to `find` and adding the `-0` option to `xargs` to insure `find` is providing filenames separated by a *nul-character* and that `xargs` is processing a list of filenames separated by the same. This prevents any whitespace or other stray characters in the filenames from causing problems, e.g.

```
find dir -type f -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 tar -cf tarfile.tar
```

The above will find all files in or below `dir` matching name `"*.png"` and provide a list of filenames separated by the *nul-character* to `xargs` for use by `tar`. You can list the files contained in the resulting archive with:

```
tar -tf tarfile.tar
```

Consider using compression (if wanted) by adding the `z` (gzipped) `j` (bzip2) or `J` (xz compression) and the appropriate extension to reduce you archive size. e.g.

```
... | xargs -0 tar -czf tarfile.tar.gz
```